# Как разложить результат из цикла по переменным?

Tags: python

Получаю из фрейма строку раскладываю на массив в цикле получаю отдельные слова. Не могу понять как разложит результат по разным переменным?

```
for indx in data.index:# получаю из фрейма строку
s = data.at[indx,1] 
  for s in fio.split(): # раскладываем полученную строку на массив
      print(s)
```

Результат

```
Тестов
Тест
Тестович
```

Comment: Если количество частей не определено (не три слова, например), то не используйте отдельные переменные, используйте список. Если ровно три слова, то цикл не нужен: `a, b, c = fio.split()`

Comment: @insolor Вы правы, спасибо большое, поставьте в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если количество частей не определено (не три слова, например), то не используйте отдельные переменные, используйте список:

```
words = fio.split()
```

Если ровно три слова, то цикл не нужен:

```
a, b, c = fio.split()
```

Answer (score 2):

в дополнение к [предыдущему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1475205/457260) ответу. на случай если в строке может оказаться больше чем 3 слова, можно подстраховаться таким образом:

```
fio = "Иван Иванович Иванов Старший"

a, b, c, *others = fio.split()
print(f'{a=}, {b=}, {c=}, {others=}')
# a='Иван', b='Иванович', c='Иванов', others=['Старший']
```

либо указать параметр maxsplit:

```
a, b, c = fio.split(maxsplit=2)
print(f'{a=}, {b=}, {c=}')
# a='Иван', b='Иванович', c='Иванов Старший'
```

Comment: А как поступить если Иван Иванович Иванов будет без отчества в этом случае программа валиться, но отработать его всё ровно нужно среди таки же с отчествами?